# Using a where statement against left outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server, nested, outer-join

I have a query that returns ALL the appointments for an advisor in a week, and what items they sold at that appointment (if non have been sold it still shows the appointment) I have done this by using a left outer join on the appointments table and ithe items table.

In this scenario I only want to display sold items in stock ( in stock is a field in the items table) 
If I use a 'where instock true'  against items, I loose all the appointments where no items have been sold ? 
Do I need to nest these queries somehow - if so how ? Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should post your current query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to what you want to do is to move the condition on the stock to the `on` clause from the `where` clause.  Presumably, your existing query looks something like this:

```
select <whatever>
from appointments a left join
     sells s
     on a.appointmentid = s.appointmentid 
where s.instock = 1;
```

The `where` clause is turning the `left join` into an `inner join`.  When there is no match, the value of `instock` is `NULL`, which does not match `1`.  The solution is to move the condition to the `on` clause:

```
select <whatever>
from appointments a left join
     sells s
     on a.appointmentid = s.appointmentid and
        s.instock = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks - this is just what I needed, ( I wasn't aware of the ON clause and have always used WHERE)

Answer (score 0):

You should use ON instead WHERE. That way, if the items aren't in stock the wont match and the right part of your join will be NULL.

```
SELECT A.*, S.* FROM appointments A LEFT JOIN sells S ON ... AND sells.instock = 1;
```

I could be more precise if I had the SQL you've tried to write.